# What is the meaning of the parenthesis () in this for loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm talking about **(myName.length + i)**

```
for(var j = i; j < (myName.length + i); j++){

     emptyArray.push(text[j]);

}
```

Comment: They make the code easy to read.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're unnecessary, strictly speaking, but they simply group that subexpression (the addition operation) just like parentheses in ordinary algebraic notation. Recall that in algebra,

```
x = (y + 3) * z
```

is different from

```
x = y + 3 * z
```

because of the parentheses. In the code in your question, however, JavaScript would interpret the expression in exactly the same way without the parentheses. People use them to emphasize what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: If you downvoted, can you explain what you find wrong with this answer?

Comment: @theatlasroom sometimes people just do that. I posted that comment before I noticed that everything in this thread was downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like they are trying to make sure it is evaluated in the correct way. Have a look at [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Answer (score -1):

adding stuff to @theatlasroom answer, it can be called [grouping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping), basically you are adding +1 to a value coming from myName.length without breaking things before or after it.

javascript could compare it before being myName.length + 1